# Unity finding child's transform component vs traversing parent's transform

Tags: lambda, unity-game-engine

so the idea is that I want to get a `GameObject` with a specific tag, which is a child of a `GameObject`, using my own method called `FindChildWithTag()`. Below there are 2 different methods, which I believe, got a similar purpose.

**FIRST**

```
void GameObject FindChildWithTag(string tag)
{
    GameObject temp = GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>().
        Select(x => x.gameObject).
        FirstOrDefault(x => x.tag == tag && x != transform);

    return temp;
}
```

**SECOND**

```
void GameObject FindChildWithTag(string tag)
{
    foreach (Transform item in transform)
    {
        if (item.tag == tag)
        {
            return item.gameObject;
        }
    }

    return null;
}
```

**But weirdly, while the first one returns null, the second one returns correctly.**

Any idea where my fault lies on the first one? Because my mind tell that those 2 method share the same goal.

Thank you.

Comment: I think your condition `x != transform` is wrong, because you attributed the x to `x.gameObject`

Comment: @RicardoReiter i think not.

Comment: but you will compare a gameObject reference with a transform reference... Or not?

Comment: @RicardoReiter afaik, same level lambda expressions doesn't affect each other. so, your opinion will be done if i put `FirstOrDefault()` inside the `Select()` expression.

Comment: Maybe your lambda expression it's wrong. If you use the Second Algorithm but use `foreach (Transform item in GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>())` instead of `foreach (Transform item in transform)`, will work?

Comment: @RicardoReiter second one already correct, but yeah, Idk what I did wrong when I asked (didn't copy paste from the actual code), maybe typo, but now it worked fine. Thank you dude

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main difference between the scripts is, that the second one looks up only to the childrens of the Transform you are searching on. (Depth 1) the first one using GetComponentsInChildren searches in all children even with greater depth's.

In my testcase both are returning the correct object if there is a correctly tagged child [image]

In the second testcase only the first script returns the object, the second script returns null
[image]

Comment: but it's doesn't make sense since the second one find it and the first one not.

Comment: @RicardoReiter yeah. that's the weird thing

Comment: When I (somehow) tried it again, it worked. I also not sure why they are different. So yeah, maybe I typo-ed or something. (The difference is last time I used name instead of tag)

Comment: They are different because GetComponentsInChildren returns children and "childrens-children"  (in the seconds case it would be "NotTagged" and "CorrectlyTagged") and if you iterate with foreach you will only get the direct childs which will be "NotTagged". This is because the "GetEnumerator()" function of Transform is implemented that way by Unity.