# Find all children with different tags -Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get a number of all children with a certain tag from the parent object.

For example if a parent object has 20 children and their tags can switch between two tags, I would want to find out how many have either tag.

I want to do it on a mouse click. I've tried using `transform.childCount` and `FindGameObjectsWithTag()` however I'm not having any luck.

Any suggestions or pointers?

Comment: This is a billion-times duplicate.  Shead, please just search first.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unity finding child's transform component vs traversing parent's transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34151721/unity-finding-childs-transform-component-vs-traversing-parents-transform)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static class Extensions {

    public static int ChildCountWithTag(this Transform tr, string tag, bool checkInactive = false) {
        int count = 0;
        Transform [] trs = tr.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(checkInactive);
        foreach(Transform t in trs) {
            if(t.gameObject.CompareTag(tag) == true) { count++; }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Then you call it as:

```
void Start() {
    int result = this.transform.ChildCountWithTag("Tag");
    int resultB = this.transform.ChildCountWithTag("OtherTag", true);
}
```

The first returns how many active with the given tag `"Tag"`, the second how many children with the tag `"OtherTag"`, including inactive ones.